# c# union of strings

Tags: c#, string

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace DW_411407_CS_CON
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string str1 = "1,2,3";
         string str2 = "3,4,5";

         Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",(str1+','+str2).Split(',').Distinct().ToArray()));
      }
   }
}
```

this c# code should make union of strings. i tried to do something but I need help. thanks

Comment: What's your question,sir?

Comment: What, **exactly**, are you trying to achieve and what, **exactly**, is going wrong? The output of this is "1,2,3,4,5" - isn't that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This code works currectly. What is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

While the technique you've shown does work in this case, I would personally split *each* string separately, and then get the union of the results using the [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) method:

```
 string str1 = "1,2,3";
 string str2 = "3,4,5";

 var stringCollection1 = str1.Split(',');
 var stringCollection2 = str2.Split(',');
 var union = stringCollection1.Union(stringCollection2);
```

Comment: nice you think to use LINQ to combine two string is affective?

Comment: @IamStalker, the code in the question already uses LINQ, just in a much less intuitive way (i.e. in this *particular* case, Distinct and Union are equivalent).

Comment: I tried to write code for this, but I mustn't use function union. just to write function which display union of two strings, something like step by step algorithm.

Comment: Looks like the OP want only distinct values from the strings.. isn't it?

Comment: @IamStalker: As noted, the original code already uses LINQ - effectively it's doing `Concat` followed by `Distinct`. I prefer `Union`, but yes, I think LINQ is well suited here - what sort of effectiveness are you thinking of?

Comment: That's not what i have asked , Jon.
I need to know it for my own purposes , might i use unmanaged code to implement string manipulations.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: `Union` does exactly that.

Comment: @IamStalker: You didn't ask anything terribly clearly, to be honest. Why would you use unmanaged code here? Do you have any *evidence* that LINQ doesn't give you the performance you need? If you have a specific situation, I suggest you ask that in a separate question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet might it be possible to use unmanaged code to work on strings instead of LINQ ?

Comment: @MIKI: It sounds like you've got a whole load of information and requirements which you haven't mentioned yet. There's no point in us trying to add any more answers until you've given us that information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @IamStalker: Of course it would be *possible*, but why on earth would you want to? The wheel here is already pretty round and shiny - why reinvent it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks Jon, like always nice talking to you, i will read the post that you have on your blog.